# How to understand compound's exchange rate

Tags: compound-protocol

With [compound](https://compound.finance/), when a user deposits a token (let's say Ether), they receive cToken in return. If we use [ETH market](https://compound.finance/markets/ETH) as an example, as of Apr 9, 2022, the exchange rate of ETH / cETH is about 50.
[image: https://compound.finance/markets/ETH]

According to [docs](https://compound.finance/docs/ctokens#exchange-rate), it is calculated as:

```
exchangeRate = (getCash() + totalBorrows() - totalReserves()) / totalSupply()
```

I understand that totalSupply() means the cETH amount, therefore (cash + borrows - reserves) should represent the ETH amount in the protocol.

However, I don't understand what do cash, borrows and reserves mean. I refer to [page
24 in reference slides by Stanford CS251](https://cs251.stanford.edu/lectures/lecture11.pdf):
[image]

But still don't have a clear answer. Any help? Thanks